# How to create a container with thin borders?

Tags: unity

I want to make a container with a thin border, for this I created a 32x32 pixel image, but by adjusting the Canvas Scaler and also setting the Anchors I noticed that at some screen resolutions the sides of the container disappear or change color, how can I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try checking "Pixel Perfect" on Canvas component.

Comment: @eLTomis, I tried but it didn't help.

Comment: Then check quality settings and turn off anti aliasing completely.

Comment: @eLTomis, Disabled anti-aliasing, but it still doesn't help.

Comment: @eLTomis, I noticed that if position and size are integer values ​​then the borders don't disappear. But how to make them integer if anchors govern them?

Comment: Last idea, try changing sprites PPU that canvas' RPPU would be a multitude of sprite's PPU (PPU = X and RPPU = X * N, or PPU = X * N and RPPU = X).

Comment: @eLTomis, TDidn't help, the default was PPU = RPPU.

Comment: Is your game view at 100%? If you have your game view set to a high resolution and zoomed out, this issue will always happen.